# Determine number of combinations of neighbours in matrix

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm looking for an analytical solution to the following problem.

In a matrix, all elements are either 0, 1 or 2. 0 means that the element is "empty", while 1 means that the element is occupied by a member of group 1 and 2 means that the element is occupied by a member of group 2. Each element occupied by a member of group 1 or group 2 in the matrix has at most 8 neighbours, defined as the adjacent matrix elements, and may have as few as 0 neighbours. Thus, we can think of the set of neighbours as the union of two subsets of in-group neighbours and out-group neighbours, where the order of the set of neighbours ranges from 0 to 8.

For example, if one element is occupied by a member of group 1 and it has one neighbour which also belongs to group 1 and two neighbours which belong to group 2, it will have one in-group neighbour and two out-group neighbours.

I want to find the total number of unique ratios of in-group members (including the member for which the neighbourhood is defined) to out-group members for all possible neighbourhoods. For example, let $k$ be the number of in-group neighbours and $N$ be the total number of neighbours. Then, the ratio of in-group to out-group is $\frac{1 + k}{1 + N}$.

For example, we have two ratios for the case of one neighbour: $\frac{1 + 0}{1 + 1} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1 + 1}{1 + 1} = 1$. For the case of two neighbours, we have three ratios: $\frac{1 + 0}{1 + 2} = \frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1 + 1}{1 + 2} = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{1 + 2}{1 + 2} = 1$, but only two ratios which are not covered in the case of one neighbour.

Any help would be much appreciated. It is easy to do computationally, but I am interested in finding an analytical solution or approach.

Comment: By in-group and out-group, do you mean groups 1 and 2?

Comment: Also, is your goal to calculate how many ratios are possible in general, or how many different ratios are present in a given matrix? EDIT: Judging from the title, I suppose it's the latter.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify this.

(i) If an element is occupied by a member of group 1. All the neighbours that also belong to group 1 are in-group neighbours and all neighbours that belong to group 2 are out-group neighbours.

(ii) The goal is to calculate how many ratios are possible in general.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! But now I have a new question: if there are $k$ in-group neighbors and $N$ total neighbors, then isn't the ratio of in-group to out-group $\frac{1+k}{N-k}$? What you are calculating is the fraction of non-empty elements in the $3\times 3$ square around an element which are in the same group as the middle element. EDIT: actually, the two problems are equal. I'll write up an explanation once I get an actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $a$ for the number of in-group neighbors and $b$ for the number of out-group neighbors. Then you are looking for the cardinality of
$$\left\{\left.\frac{1+a}{1+a+b}\;\right|\; a,b\geq0,\;a+b\leq8\right\},$$
(This set gives the ratios of in-group elements to total non-empty elements) We can apply any bijective map to this set: in particular, applying $x\mapsto\frac1x-1$, we find that the previous set has the same cardinality as
$$A:=\left\{\left.\frac{b}{1+a}\;\right|\;a,b\geq 0,\;a+b\leq8\right\}.$$
(This set gives the ratios of out-group elements to in-group elements. This is why, in the comments, I said that the two problems were equivalent.) Isolating the case where $b=0$ and writing $a'=a+1$, we find that
$$\begin{aligned}
A&=\{0\}\amalg\left\{\left.\frac{b}{a'}\;\right|\;a',b\geq 1,\;a+b\leq9\right\}\\
&=\{0\}\amalg\left\{\left.(a',b)\;\right|\;a',b\geq 1,\;a+b\leq9,\;\gcd(a',b)=1\right\}.
\end{aligned}$$
The idea is that if $\frac{b}{a'}$ is not a reduced expression, then we can divide both sides by $d\geq 1$, which gives a pair of integers $(\frac{a'}d,\frac bc)$ such that $\frac{a'}d+\frac bc\leq 9$, so the fraction is already taken into account.

Thus the number of ratios of in-group and out-group elements is
$$\#A=1+\#\{(a',b)\mid a',b\geq 1,\;a'+b\leq9,\;\gcd(a',b)=1\}.$$
I'm not too sure how to simplify this, but this set shouldn't be too hard to calculate.